# Xamarin portability between Android and IPhone

Tags: android, iphone, xamarin

I must build an app for both Android and Iphone.

Xamarin caught my eye right away, since I am a .NET dev.
I know I can use Xamarin to build apps for both platforms, but that means that I must "rewrite" them for each platfom?

Are the easily portable from Mono Touch to Mono for Android (or vice-versa)?
Did any one have experience making this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Non GUI code is pretty portable, so it would depend quite a bit on how well you separate GUI from logic.

Answer (score 4):

If you take it a step further, you could use something like MvvmCross to maximize the amount of code you can share cross platform.  Check out my Wsh Lst project for an example of how this would be done: https://github.com/Redth/WshLst